# What happens if positrons, instead of electrons, are decelerated inside an X-ray tube?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electrons, antimatter, x-rays

When charged particles are accelerated, they produce Bremsstrahlung radiation. If the necessary changes are made to an X-ray tube to emit positrons and then decelerate them, will the effect be the same as normal X-ray operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say there will be a huge effect. I am not sure if acceleration vs. deceleration is very important, but there will also be gamma radiation due to annihilation of the positrons with electrons of the matter.

EDIT: (11/25/2016) As for Bremsstrahlung of positrons, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.5532 (Abstract: Fully relativistic treatment of the electron-atom and positron-atom bremsstrahlung is reported. The calculation is based on the partial-wave expansion of the Dirac scattering states in an external atomic field. A comparison of the electron and positron bremsstrahlung is presented for the single and double differential cross sections and the Stokes parameters of the emitted photon. It is demonstrated that the electron-positron symmetry of the bremsstrahlung spectra, which is nearly exact in the nonrelativistic regime, is to a large extent removed by the relativistic effects.)

Comment: Correct. If the target is anti-matter, there will be no difference. If the target is matter, well, you will get some x-rays and lots of gammas. Some of  those hose x-rays will still be characteristic x-rays of the target, which mainly come from the incident particle scattering core-level electrons out, allowing higher shell electrons to drop in to the now-empty orbital.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since the X-ray photons are not made of neither matter or antimatter. The symmetry laws imply the electron and the positron have the same properties related to radiation emission.